# How do I override the use of /tmp when building with Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am building a [large Bazel project](https://www.tensorflow.org/) in a cloud VM with `/tmp` in a small filesystem (~8 GB). Occasionally my build fails with the error `Not all outputs were created`: the filesystem containing `/tmp` is at 99% of capacity, and `/tmp` contains many Bazel build artifacts.

How can I override the temporary directory that Bazel uses? I tried setting the `TEMP` and `TMPDIR` environment variables when starting `bazel build`, but this did not help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `--output_base` to put all output in a non-default directory:

```
bazel --output_base=/dir/with/more/free/space build //foo
```

However, I don't think Bazel will use `/tmp` (by default) after you've installed it (the installer does use /tmp), so perhaps you're hitting a different problem.

Comment: TensorFlow deactivate sandboxing and they might have huge test that writes to /tmp and does not clean correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [--test_tmpdir=<a_path>](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_tmpdir) command line argument to the `bazel` command.

```
--test_tmpdir=<a path> default: see description
    Specifies the base temporary directory for 'bazel test' to use.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [configure_make](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/blob/master/tools/build_defs/configure.bzl) rule from [rules_foreign_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/tree/master), unfortunately you have no way to influence where the built deps are stored.
See https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/blob/master/cc_configure_make/def.bzl#L44

```
"tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)",
"tmpinstalldir=$(mktemp -d)",
```

Comment: rules_foreign_cc has moved from the master branch to the main. and in the main there is a commit, which add a proper sandboxing

Answer (score -1):

You may also refer Bazel's manual, describing [output directory layout](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html)